# HttpClient is forcing port 80 for https request

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have a program that is trying to send a request to another program using https.
This code sample is leaving out the building of content, but is an example of how I'm sending:

```cs
var uri = new Uri("https://somehost:443/somepath");
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var result = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
```

When I do the PostAsync, I get an exception back saying "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it *[redacted]*:80".

I don't understand why it's trying to go to port 80.  I even specifically tried to force port 443.  My initial attempts left that off and just trusted it to do the right thing with https.

Some Googling, which produced mostly stackoverflow results, hinted that there may be a proxy involved.  But as far as I can tell, there's not.

This is .NET 4.5.1

Comment: Did you try without specifying any port in URL? I think HttpClient will try to use "default" port for every protocol (80 for http, 443 for https). Still, the exception you are getting seems very weird to me

Comment: Yes, that was what I had to begin with.  I only added port 443 when that wasn't working.

Comment: Next try I would make, connect to some well known https site, such https://www.Google.com, and verify if you get the same error

Comment: We found part of the problem.  The "target machine *actively* refused it" part of the message was a clue.  The request is getting there but because something (yet unknown) was converting the request from https to http, the session cookie, which is marked as secure, is getting dropped.

Comment: Sounds like it's redirecting. What happens if you make the same call with Postman?

Comment: We still don't know why it's getting redirected to port 80, but we think that's some network infrastructure component. It turns out that "target machine *actively* refused it" in this case meant that the service actually *got* the request, but its middleware was checking for a cookie that wasn't getting passed and doing something to actively refuse the connection rather than returning a 401 Not Authorized or something that would have been easier to diagnose.